# Why my buttons have different colors while they have same classes

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

Doing simple interface for news app, I have six buttons, two of them are blue (btn-primary) while all have same classes.

Full code here https://codepen.io/tarekhassab/pen/Oojdgw?editors=1010

```
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary"> Technology </button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-priamry"> Business </button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-priamry"> Science </button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary"> Entertainment </button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-priamry"> Health </button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-priamry"> Sports </button>
```

Answer (score 2):

Check out this buttons, They have incorrect spelling of `btn-priamry`

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-priamry"> Business </button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-priamry"> Science </button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-priamry"> Health </button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-priamry"> Sports </button>
```

Should be `btn-primary`

Comment: @tarekhassan: if you're using Visual Studio, you can install Web Essentials extension (Tools -> Extensions and Updates -> Online). Then you would have the bootstrap class hinting so that you don't have to type the classes manually.